# how to auto set infowindow content in google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

1. When  marker is top then if I click then marker position set a map center but I don't want to change map position from top
2. When I click from bottom like that I will go to top position automatically  see this image : [actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XBZd.png)   but I want to scroll
   top automtically on top position like this [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssQ1.png)
3. Left and right working fine based on auto position

**note : infowindow content show from bottom not from top**

see my js fiddle

```js
function initMap() {

        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the centre of the map. In my case it is the same as the position of the map pin.
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

        var html = '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<a id="exampleMenu1">' +
            '<div class="context">Example 1</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<a id="exampleMenu2">' +
            '<div class="example">Example 2</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<a id="exampleMenu3">' +
            '<div class="example">Example 3</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<a id="exampleMenu4">' +
            '<div class="example">Example 4</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<a id="exampleMenu5">' +
            '<div class="example">Example 5</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>';


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: html
        });


        //Create a marker pin to add to the map
        var marker;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the position of the pin
            map: map,
            //title: "Derby",
            icon: "http://www.codeshare.co.uk/images/blue-pin.png", //if you comment this out or delete it you will get the default pin icon.
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    
  //  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map {
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100vh);
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {
            position: absolute;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 200px;
            left: 58px;
            transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding: 12px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after {
           display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question??

Comment: O.o i already mention on the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any difference between what your info window currenlty looks like vs what you expect it to look like. Can you clarify or explain further what is wrong with your current info window and what you are trying to change/fix?

Comment: @evan when i click on marker then map should be automatically scroll(top,right,bottom,left) based on marker infowindow content .for example : if marker is bottom of the screen then i click then it should be go to the top with content show bottom of the markerinfowindow content show properly..

Comment: Thanks I think I understand what you mean now, please check out my answer and let me know if this is indeed what you wanted. If not please clarify further and I'll modify my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is center the map to the infowindow when the marker is clicked, right? In that case, you can modify your click event listener as follows:

```
    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setCenter(infowindow.getPosition());
    });
```

Hope this helps!